# Ordering Display Images with mouse c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I uploaded some images into my database, and they are displying in index page in the order they are uploaded.

> I need to change order in display page using mouse drag
> But I need to arrange them as i want. As which image comes first..

On changing the images I need to change the Order field too, which i set autoincrement when creating..

> The Image Table has following fields
>
> ID
>
> Image
>
> Order

my code is like this

View

```
<div class="row" id="ImagesID">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
       if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Image/" + item.Image)))
       {
          <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("/Image/{0}", item.Image))" type="image/jpeg">
       }
   }
</div>
```

controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Images.ToList());
    }
```

create Controller i add this code

```
 public ActionResult Create(Image image, HttpPostedFileBase ImageID)
    {
        var sp = db.Images.ToList();

       // Adding order according to DB
        if (sp.Count != 0)
        {
            order = db.Images.Max(p => p.Orders);
            image.Orders = order + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            image.Orders = 1;
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             db.Images.Add(image);
             db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(bannerImage);
    }
```

Help me, Thank You

Comment: the simplest way i can think of is to add an up and a down arrow to your view then require user to click on the image and move it via up and down arrow.

Comment: Thanks, I think it will do

Comment: to your table where images are kept add a column - sortOrder to keep the sort order of the images.

Comment: @JustLearning its not what really i needed, but for now this looks good and works correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a ImageList so you can sort with orders paramater

```
public ActionResult Create(Image image, HttpPostedFileBase ImageID)
    {

var sp = db.Images.OrderBy(c=>c.Order).ToList(); // sort with Order
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             db.Images.Add(image);
             db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(sp);

}
```

Comment: thank you, but my mistake. this is not i meant. i need to change images on the display page

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Images.OrderBy(x=>x.Order).ToList());
}
```

**Update:** 
Make your UI Dragable using [Jquery plugin](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#ImagesID" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
```

Comment: thank you, but i need to change images on the display page

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return View(db.Images.OrderByDescending(o => o.Order).ToList());
```

or

```
return View(db.Images.OrderBy(o => o.Order).ToList());
```

Comment: thanks, but i would like to change the order in display page, by moving images with mouse